# selecting closest anchor element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with one link as follows

```
 <td>
      <a href="#" class="topiclink">@item.Topic</a>
   </td>
```

I want to select data of @item.topic.
I tried using

```
  $('.topiclink').click(function (e) {
  var val = $(this).closest('a');
        alert(val)
    });
```

and many others but nothing seems working in this case.Thank for the help.

Comment: you need to use `alert(val.text())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var val = $(this).text();
```

Is enough to get you that

Answer (score 4):

What you've clicked is already an anchor, so:

```
$('.topiclink').on('click', function (e) {
    var val = $(this).text();
    alert(val);
}
```

I'm also using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) here, because `.val()` should only be used on HTML input elements.

Comment: Upvoting because you're right and you were clearly reading more attentively than I was...

Comment: @DavidThomas Much obliged =D

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the value '@item.Topic' on click of the anchor or any anchor, that is, you may use below code:

```
$('a').click( function () {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of errors in your code !
Your  element is already a '.topiclink' class, so why do you want the closest element ?
Just use $(this) to access your element.
val() not return the html of the element, you should use $(this).html();

```
 $('.topiclink').click(function (e) {
    alert($(this).html()); 
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `InnerHTML` or `HTML()` it gives you the HTML elements inside the Anchor tag not the Text... See here : http://jsfiddle.net/pacFf/3/