# How to pass value in a jQuery function without the help of onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameter-passing

I am facing a problem in which I need to pass either one or multiple parameter to a `javascript` function. For example

```
<a href="#" OnClick="Delete(1,'q');" > X </a>
<a href="#" OnClick="Delete(2,'u');" > X </a>
```

But I am trying to avoid this `onclick` attribute from the html end. So I have used this way

```
<a  href="javascript://" title="Delete" id="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/1" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete1</a>
<a  href="javascript://" title="Delete" id="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete2</a>
<a  href="javascript://" title="Delete" id="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete3</a>
```

And written the `jQuery` function like this to capture my click function from the link

```
$("#actRemove").each(function() {
   $(this).on("click", function () {
      alert($(this).data("action"));
   });
});
```

But alas!! I am undone. This link works only for the first anchor `Delete1` none of the anchors are working. Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdmanandamohon/09ywjraz/1/) link. I have gone through these answers [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311503/how-to-pass-a-razor-value-to-a-jquery-function-in-an-mvc-view), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179297/how-to-pass-a-razor-variable-to-jquery-function-as-parameter/5179316#5179316), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370359/passing-parameters-to-a-jquery-function), [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169089/selecting-closest-anchor-element-using-jquery), [Q5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute/20943248), [Q6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery). Each of those question have the solution in the first way using `onclick` and passed the parameter to the function.I am thinking differently. Moreover my another question is, **is there any way to pass parameter to a `jQuery` `function` without writing `onclick` in the `html` attribute?** I know that jQuery function is capable to receive the parameter, but how can I send it to the function from the html end?

Comment: All elements must have Unique IDs

Comment: instead of using ids use same class in each anchor

Comment: @lazycoder , you used same id for all the anchor tags

Comment: Id's are unique, classes may be duplicate. you should give the same class for each three anchor tags, and fire the event on class not id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `id` use `class` selector:-

HTML:-

```
<a  href="javascript:viod(0);" title="Delete" class="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/1" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete1</a>
<a  href="javascript:viod(0);" title="Delete" class="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete2</a>
<a  href="javascript:viod(0);" title="Delete" class="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete3</a>
```

jQuery:-

```
$(".actRemove").on("click", function () {
  alert($(this).data("action"));
});
```

***Working demo:-***

```js
$(".actRemove").on("click", function () {
  alert($(this).data("action"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  href="javascript:viod(0);" title="Delete" class="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/1" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete1</a>
<a  href="javascript:viod(0);" title="Delete" class="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete2</a>
<a  href="javascript:viod(0);" title="Delete" class="actRemove" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete3</a>
```

***Note:-***

`id` used as `unique-selector` in jQuery,while `class` used as a `group-selector`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way

```
<a  href="javascript://" title="Delete" id="actRemove_1" data-action="/List/Delete/1" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete1</a>
<a  href="javascript://" title="Delete" id="actRemove_2" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete2</a>
<a  href="javascript://" title="Delete" id="actRemove_3" data-action="/List/Delete/2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Delete3</a>



$("a[id^='actRemove_']").on("click", function () {
     alert($(this).data("action"));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of an HTML object directly in javascript without passing it with onclick using:

```
var object_id = document.getElementById('object_id').value;
```